# Is the AccessControlList on any other more generic Core Service object types?

Tags: core-service

I am setting the access rights on a category following the solution in this post:  [Set Access Rights on Categories using the Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/set-access-rights-on-categories-using-the-core-service)

I would like to make my code more generic and am searching for a more general type of ObjectData that I can use instead of CategoryData.  I have tried the following with no luck:

- RepositoryLocalObjectData
- VersionedItemData

Is the AccessControlList on any other more generic object types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrganizationalItemData has the AccessControlList Property, so you could try that.