# Setting permissions on multiple Categories

Tags: 2011, taxonomy, security

Is there a way in the GUI to set permissions on multiple Categories at once or will it require Core Service code ([example](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/set-access-rights-on-categories-using-the-core-service/1041#1041))?

I have to set about 40+ to set to all the same permission-set.

Comment: Managed to knock something together using the example I linked to.

Comment: Cool. If the set includes multiple groups you might also consider consolidating or grouping them into fewer groups to simplify changes across Category access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no straight forward way to do so in GUI, you may need to write a Core Service code for it.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for Powershell.

Comment: Yes - I've done it with Powershell ages ago - I'll try to tidy my script up a bit and share it somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to do this in the standard GUI, however, please see my [blog article on the subject](http://www.indivirtual.nl/blog/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/), where I show how to do this from a relatively straightforward Powershell script.

With some boilerplate code in place, the script to set permissions on a category ends up looking like this:

```
$catPermsTest = $core.Read("/webdav/01%20Definitions/PermsTest", $defaultReadOptions)
addPermissions $group $catPermsTest Read
```

Comment: Excellent Post Dom :)