# Best way to handle categories and keywords security for newly created category

Tags: workflow, security, automatic-activity

I am implementing security as a per category basis for user groups. If we add new category in that case how we can handle automatic security.
I mean is, I need to create security again on newly created category.
Is there any best way to implement security once on multiple categories?
Showing property disable in my Tridion system

Comment: How is showing properties disabled for you? Whoever creates the Category could have rights to manage permissions as well.

Comment: Have you already looked at http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/4971/129 ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way implementing security on multiple categories.

BUT you can make it automated (while creating a category) by using the `Event System` to implement security.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Category within Tridion, the Default Groups are automatically assigned Permissions on that Category (of varying degrees of Read, Write, Localize and Delete).

[image]

If you have followed [best practice](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/07/sdl-tridion-authorization.html), and used sub-Groups of the Default ones (e.g `French Chief Editor` is a sub-Group of the (default) `Chief Editor` Group on a specified number of Publications (e.g. the Publications related to the French site)), then all of your users should already have Permissions (of varying degrees) for the Publications that they can see and have `Category Management` Rights on.

If you need to change the Permissions from those assigned to the Default Groups (for your sub-Groups), then you could create a tool to do this using the Core Service (or do it manually on each new Category).

It is worth noting that Content Porter does not export Permissions on organisational items (or User and Group security settings), so a Core Service tool may be the best approach for applying this consistently across your DTAP environments. (See [Non-exportable items](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8) in the online documentation (login required) for more information)